# Axios Get request return html not data SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

need some help. I'm trying to fetch data from my db using axios. My backend is Laravel. I have a 200 status http request but it returns the whole html not the data I'm expecting.

> Here is my code for route

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostController@ajaxCall');

Route::post('/home', 'PostController@store');
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

> Here is my code for Home.vue for Axios request

```
 export default {
    components: {addForm},
    data () {
        return{
            posts:[]
        }
    },
    created() {
      axios.get('/home').then(response => this.posts = response.data);
    }
}
```

> For my controller

```
public function ajaxCall(){
     return response(Post::all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you get to the ajaxCall() method by using the route '/home', but with axios, you are hitting "/" which returns a view called Welcome. Maybe you need to change the path you use in axios to '/home'?

Comment: I was able to change that. Still the same. I didnt get the data im expecting.

Comment: What does the html that you are getting back look like? I do a lot of Vue stuff with a Laravel backend. I end up using Postman to test the routes. Sometimes Laravel doesn't recognize all the routes immediately. The setup I have uses Caffeinated Modules, and I have to run either `artisan cache:clear` or `artisan modules:optimize` to get the routes to show. Otherwise, I don't see much different from what I would do. I usually use the mounted() method instead of created(), but that shouldn't matter. (I don't know Vue all that well).

Comment: I do some updates on my codes. Now it returns the data I need unfortunately the view or any component vue doesn't load. I really dont know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but maybe someone else is looking for the solution
I was also facing this in SPA using laravel and VUE.

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

SPA has this route, so whenever you write any other get route your app will redirect you to the home page, to avoid this either move this route at the end of your web.php
or write your other routes in api.php file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved it by changing the GET method to POST method.
Try that. It might help